# How to use PyMongo with Flask Blueprints?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

What is the correct way of picking up *mongo* object inside Blueprints?

Here is how I have my parent `login.py`:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
from child import child
from child2 import child2


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(child2.child2)
app.register_blueprint(child.child)
```

in my `child.py`

```
from app import app
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

mongo = PyMongo(app)
child = Blueprint('child', __name__)
```

`child2.py` is the same structure as child:

```
from app import app
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
    
mongo = PyMongo(app)
child2 = Blueprint('child2', __name__)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
raise Exception('duplicate config_prefix "%s"' % config_prefix)
Exception: duplicate config_prefix "MONGO"
```

---

I've tried the following in the blueprint

```
mongo = app.data.driver
```

but that raises error. Here is full traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 12, in <module>
    from child import child
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/child/child.py", line 13, in <module>
    mongo = PyMongo(app) #blueprint
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config_prefix)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 121, in init_app
    raise Exception('duplicate config_prefix "%s"' % config_prefix)
Exception: duplicate config_prefix "MONGO"
(xxx)xxx@linux:~/xxx$ python login.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 12, in <module>
    from courses import courses
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/child/child.py", line 13, in <module>
    mongo = PyMongo(app) #blueprint
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config_prefix)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 121, in init_app
    raise Exception('duplicate config_prefix "%s"' % config_prefix)
Exception: duplicate config_prefix "MONGO"
```

Once my app has created the connection, how should I pick it up in my blueprints?

So the question is how can one structure the connection strings to the db in each of the blueprints. Here is the file structure:

```
login.py
config.py
/child/child.py
/child2/child2.py
```

here is the `config.py`

```
MONGO_DBNAME = 'xxx'

MONGO_URL = os.environ.get('MONGO_URL')
if not MONGO_URL:
    MONGO_URL = "mongodb://xxx:xxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:55822/heroku_xxx";

MONGO_URI = MONGO_URL
```

I've tried the suggestion below in answers, but this did not work. See my comments below that prospective answer.

Comment: Do you have `mongo = PyMongo(app)` in both login.py and child.py?

Comment: Can you please show us the file structure of your project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the issues with the approach of performing an import in the blueprint as was suggest by Emanuel Ey, turns out that it causes a circular import. After much playing, it turns out that the only way (I could find) was to create a separate file called `database.py` that connects to the database and then I can import this connection to by blueprint as follows:

```
child.py

from database import mongo
courses = Blueprint('courses', __name__)
```

and my `database.py`

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo()
```

and the app, login.py but has to initialize the database

```
from database import mongo
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
mongo.init_app(app) # initialize here!

from child import child 
from child import2 child2

app.register_blueprint(child.child)
app.register_blueprint(child2.child2)
```

Comment: You may want to generalize that even further by changing database.py to settings.py and setting your various config items there.

Answer (score 1):

You're are initializing the PyMongo driver twice, once in `child.py` and a second time on `child2.py`.

Try initializing the PyMongo connection in the file which sets up your app object and then import it in the children:

login.py:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
from child import child
from child2 import child2


app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

# Register blueprints
def register_blueprints(app):
    # Prevents circular imports
    app.register_blueprint(child2.child2)
    app.register_blueprint(child.child)

register_blueprints(app)
```

in child.py

```
from app import app, mongo

child = Blueprint('child', __name__)
```

child2.py:

```
from app import app, mongo

child2 = Blueprint('child2', __name__)
```

Comment: The import fails, i.e. when trying `from app import app, mongo`, as does: `from app import mongo as mongo`, with the following issue: `ImportError: cannot import name 'mongo' `

Comment: Also the app,config is before the `app = Flask (__name__)`